# How do you send an HTML envelope to a user via email, from a headless API, that has not created an account on DOCUSIGN?

Tags: authentication, docusignapi, impersonation, headless

I'm sure I am missing something here but...

I have an angular application that allows users to fill out forms.  The application calls a backend NODEJS service that has a responsibility of building the HTML envelope and document to sign.  This back-end service does not have access to a browser.

I have 2 options for flow:

1. *User fills out form -> clicks sign button -> back-end service called to gather the url for the user to redirect to in order to get a code back (consent) -> **USER DOES NOT LOGIN TO DOCUSIGN** -> redirect back to application -> get token with users code -> prepare envelope on BEHALF of the user -> send application the ceremony URL -> user redirects to ceremony -> signs document -> redirect back to application.*
2. *User fills out form -> clicks sign button -> back-end service called to create envelope and tell DOCUSIGN to send an EMAIL to the user which I don't want to sign up for DOCUSIGN. (Effectively removing the need for them to create an account with DOCUSIGN because I am sending an email and they can authenticate him by knowing he is coming from his own email). -> user signs document through email -> (Would be nice for application to get redirected back to but not necessary)

- 

All examples and chats I have seen discuss only having to login one time.  Well in flow 1, I don't want the USER, signing the document, to login or have to make an account for this one signing.  And in flow 2, I can't seem to grasp how to keep the back-end service authenticated if it is a BACK-END service.  It's headless. No Browser.

These guys are so large that I figure it's something I'm not grasping here.

I understand to impersonate the user, I would need his consent. And possibly... because they don't KNOW the user without him signing up for an account to verify his email, they can't offer consent to a user they can't verify email with.  So if that is the case, I would want to authenticate my BACK-END user to send emails so they can just click the email, it MIGHT verify in DOCUSIGN without having to sign up for account, and offer the contract to the user to sign on the spot from the email WITHOUT asking for credentials or NEW account.

If you are going to answer this with a link back to DOCUSIGN authentication examples. Or suggest use a JWT to authenticate from BACK-END services... please explain in detail the steps to authenticate my BACK-END user and keep him authenticated without using a web-browser or how to use the users consent from a redirect from DOCUSIGN without the user having to EVER create an account.

I have tried sending the user to the redirect URL with success if they already have their credentials cached in browser or already have a DOCUSIGN user.  The flow works fine there. I get the users code, exchange it for token, create envelope, redirect user to ceremony, redirect back to application after signing complete.

I have read a bunch of articles that all point back to DOCUSIGN help with authenticating 1 of 3 ways with a browser.  I need no browser login, or a better understanding of how to avoid the user creating a DOCUSIGN account.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Signer, user that signs, does NOT need to have a DocuSign account. They do not need to log in to DocuSign in order to sign. They can sign via email or embedded in your app, but they do NOT need to have an account or log in.
2. Your app's back end needs an access token to make API calls. This doesn't change the headless nature or the fact that it's back end. A token is a long string that your app uses to authenticate. This authentication is tied to a user in DocuSign that has an account. That is NOT the user that signs, but the user that make the API call. You have to have a user that makes an API call.
3. You can get a token using [JWT authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) and your back end can generate it using the [Node.js SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/node/) (npm package) without the need for UI or for anyone to log in.

Comment: Thanks.  Very clear.  Didn't understand the idea that consent needed to be given only once and thought it needed to be given on each request or at least length of token expiration.